# Port forwarding not working although port is open

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, webserver

I'm attempting to run a web server from home.

What I have done so far:

1) Configured static IP on router.
2) Configured port forwarding on router.
3) Configured windows firewall - inbound rule.

What I can do:

1) I am running XAMMP and can see homepage on 127.0.0.1
2) See open port 80 (or any other port if I open it) via https://portchecker.co
3) See homepage from my static IP (PC)

But can't access homepage from my IP.

How can I solve this problem?

[image: add rules manually]

[image: enable]

[image: protocols and ports]

Comment: What's the "Listen" option in `XAMPP/Apache/conf/httpd.conf` set to?

Comment: I can see homepage from web server and from other devices via 192.168.1.24. But not from external ip.

Answer (score 1):

The remote port should be set to `any`.

A connection to your web server will use port 80 on the web server's sid ("local" from the POV of the Windows firewall), but may originate from any port ("remote" from the POV of the Windows firewall)

Comment: Thanks for that - but still not loading although changed.

Comment: Have you made the same mistake on the port forwarding router?

Comment: The router screenshot is above - * indicates external hosts